# HTTP 403 vs 200 from different user-agents - DENO function

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api, deno

**Context:**
I have a small Deno function deployed that takes a JSON body with three values. Those values are used in a fetch request to a API endpoint. Then return the data back to the requester.

**Problem:**
Testing with postman I get a 200 with the data. Testing with a tool like reqbin I get a 403.

**What I think:**
I think it has something to do with the fact that the reqbin request is redirected. But how does the end API know that if I "catch" the request in Deno and make a new fetch request to the end API?

**My code:**

```
import "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/load.ts";
import { listenAndServe } from "https://deno.land/std/http/mod.ts";
import { queryString } from "./queryString.js";

listenAndServe({ port: 8080 }, async (req) => {
  //Check method
  if (req.method != "POST") {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: "Method not allowed" }), {
      status: 405,
    });
  }

  //Checking API key
  const token = await req.headers.get("x-api-key");
  if (token != Deno.env.get("KEY")) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: "Not authorized" }), {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      status: 401,
    });
  }

  const body = await req.json();
  /*
    {
      id: "123",
      currency: "USD",
      country: "US"
    }
  */

  if (!typeof body.id == "string" || body.id == undefined) {
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ error: "No ID or ID is in the wrong format" }),
      {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        status: 400,
      }
    );
  }

  const params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: queryString,
      variables: {
        id: body.id,
        currency: body.currency,
        country: body.country,
      },
    }),
  };

  const getDetails = await fetch("https://url.com", params);
  const getDetailsStatus = getDetails.status;

  if (getDetailsStatus == 200) {
    const detailData = await getDetails.json();
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(detailData), {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      status: 200,
    });
  } else {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: await getDetails.text() }), {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      status: getDetailsStatus,
    });
  }
});
```

**Headers:**

```
const headers = {
    postmanHeadersIncommingToDeno: {
        accept: "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        connection: "keep-alive",
        "content-length": "104",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        host: "api-test.deno.dev",
        "postman-token": "bfa856c6-82688ac6d",
        referer: "http://api-test.deno.dev/",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0",
        "x-api-key": "xxxxx",
        "x-forwarded-for": "22.22.222.222"
    },
    APIresponseFromPostmanRequest: {
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "alt-svc": 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400',
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "cf-cache-status": "DYNAMIC",
        "cf-ray": "6d7600655f39fa9c-AMS",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        date: "Wed, 02 Feb 2022 19:59:43 GMT",
        etag: 'W/"556e-ki5bDB2SON5e6pQGbUxfMFEP0Jo"',
        "expect-ct": 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
        server: "cloudflare",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload",
        vary: "Accept-Encoding",
        "x-amz-apigw-id": "M7hbZEtgoAMFjoA=",
        "x-amzn-remapped-connection": "keep-alive",
        "x-amzn-remapped-date": "Wed, 02 Feb 2022 19:59:43 GMT",
        "x-amzn-remapped-server": "nginx/1.19.1",
        "x-amzn-requestid": "7cc10db3-d179-4ed5-8428-3b1bb15279c7",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-61fae2af-3a723f2479db4356007f1696",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
        "x-dns-prefetch-control": "off",
        "x-download-options": "noopen",
        "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "x-origin-region": "us-east-1",
        "x-origin-server": "nginx",
        "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
    },
    reqbinIncommingToDeno: {
        accept: "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "deflate, gzip",
        "content-length": "104",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        host: "api-tester.deno.dev",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4...",
        "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "x-forwarded-for": "111.111.111.111",
        "x-real-ip": "22.22.222.222"
    },
    APIresponseFromReqbinRequest: {
        "alt-svc": 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400',
        "cf-ray": "6d760504cac382b6-IAD",
        "content-type": "text/html",
        date: "Wed, 02 Feb 2022 20:02:52 GMT",
        "expect-ct": 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
        server: "cloudflare",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload",
        vary: "Accept-Encoding",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the request and response headers indicate?

Comment: @jsejcksn i updated the post with the headers.